# Poisson Regression Model Issue

Tags: python, dataframe, regression, modeling, poisson

I am trying to predict the count for a particular data set over varying time periods. Hence, I'm using an offset to account for these different time periods.

However, while trying to fit the model I get this error:
LinAlgError: Singular matrix
I don't know what this means.
This is my code and sample dataset

```
glm = statsmodels.formula.api.gee
model = glm("Number_Of_Claims ~ Number_Of_Users + Number_Of_Vehicles + 
Total_Miles + Category_Adults + Category_Business + Category_Senior + 
Category_MedExp + Territory_1 + Territory_2 + Territory_3 + Territory_4 + 
Territory_5 + Liability_Exposure + PIP_Exposure ", groups=None, 
data=train_init, offset = train_init.Exposure_Term, 
family=Poisson())

results = model.fit()
```

This is my sample data
[Sample of training dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QDmUC.png)

My continuous variables are Number_Of_Users, Number_Of_Vehicles and Total Miles
The rest are dummy variables

Comment: After looking [here](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/gee.html) I can supposed you to specify parameters `cow_struct` and `family`. Some [examples](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.genmod.generalized_estimating_equations.GEE.html#statsmodels.genmod.generalized_estimating_equations.GEE) from docs here maybe can help you

Comment: Problem Solved. My offset in the GLM was time in days which is too high and frankly does not make sense. Hence, I took the time in months and the model works fine